# Magento2 - Change position of wishlist on catalog-category view page

Tags: magento2, css, xml, less

I want to change the position of Wishlist icon on the top of image .

Do I have to achieve this through `xml` or through `css`?

I tried through `xml` but I couldn't move it over the image.

Here is the screen shot:

[image: expected output]

Comment: try with css. that will be easy.

Comment: I know that it is easy but is it a proper way? @sudo55

Comment: Check the template from where it is coming. if template is from core vendor the over ride it to your theme and modify the templates accordingly. both the wish list and compare are under actions-secondary   element .

Comment: Wishlist button comes from a different template and the product-info comes from another template . How come this can be acheived? @VinitKumar

Comment: The Block **category.product.addto.wishlist** ,**category.product.addto.compare** and  **category.product.addto ** is responsible for wish list and compare Icons . You can modify the **catalog_category_view.xml** in your theme or in **default.xml** file and using move tag  under **details.renderers**

Answer (score 0):

Copy list.phtml from “vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml” and paste into “app/design/frontend/vendor/theme-name/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml”
We can add changes in class="actions-secondary" to get the wishlist to top

Answer (score 0):

You can override your file below path and move your html after product image like below screenshot [here](https://prnt.sc/1vy86pk)

```
app/design/frontend/{{YOUR THEME NAME HERE}}/default/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml
```

Add this css

```
.actions-secondary {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 9;
}
```